# How to add Value child in child in Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

### Main file

Hello guys, I've to do something like this, as shown in the picture below -
[image]

but I don't know how to do this!!, And the thing is that document is not that clear to understand
and need someone to help me ...

```
UserSongUploadDetails user_song_upload_details = new UserSongUploadDetails(user_uid,song_artist_name_field_string,
                                            song_artist_name_field_string,
                                            song_description_field_string,
                                            date_time_formatter,
                                            song_firebase_url);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    user_song_database_refrence = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
user_song_database_refrence.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).setValue(user_song_upload_details);
```

### Users.java file

putting all these values to setValue(), as you can see.

```
public class UserSongUploadDetails {
    private String user_id;
    private String song_name;
    private String song_artist;
    private String song_description;
    private String song_upload_time_stamp;
    private Uri song_storage_url;

    UserSongUploadDetails(){

    }

    UserSongUploadDetails(String user_id, String song_name, String song_artist, String song_description, String song_upload_time_stamp, Uri song_storage_url){
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.song_name = song_name;
        this.song_artist = song_artist;
        this.song_description = song_description;
        this.song_upload_time_stamp = song_upload_time_stamp;
        this.song_storage_url = song_storage_url;
    }

    public String getUser_id(){
        return user_id;
    }

    public String getSong_name(){
        return song_name;
    }

    public String getSong_artist(){
        return song_artist;
    }

    public String getSong_description(){
        return song_description;
    }

    
    public String getSong_upload_time_stamp(){
        return song_upload_time_stamp;
    }

    public Uri getSong_storage_url() {
        return song_storage_url;
    }
```

### Errors

```
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Match the class structure to the database structure**

You need to match the structure between your custom Java Class and Database Structure. In your case, the Java Class structure is as follows:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email_id;
    private AudioUpload audio_upload;
    
    public class AudioUpload implements Serializable {
        private String song_artist;
        private String song_genre;
        private String song_name;
        private String song_url;

        public AudioUpload(String song_artist, String song_genre, String song_name, String song_url) {
            this.song_artist = song_artist;
            this.song_genre = song_genre;
            this.song_name = song_name;
            this.song_url = song_url;
        }

        public String getSong_artist() {
            return song_artist;
        }

        public void setSong_artist(String song_artist) {
            this.song_artist = song_artist;
        }

        public String getSong_genre() {
            return song_genre;
        }

        public void setSong_genre(String song_genre) {
            this.song_genre = song_genre;
        }

        public String getSong_name() {
            return song_name;
        }

        public void setSong_name(String song_name) {
            this.song_name = song_name;
        }

        public String getSong_url() {
            return song_url;
        }

        public void setSong_url(String song_url) {
            this.song_url = song_url;
        }
    }

    public User(String name, String email_id, AudioUpload audio_upload) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email_id = email_id;
        this.audio_upload = audio_upload;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }

    public AudioUpload getAudio_upload() {
        return audio_upload;
    }

    public void setAudio_upload(AudioUpload audio_upload) {
        this.audio_upload = audio_upload;
    }
}
```

In order to pass object to `setValue()`, your custom class **must** implements `Serializable`. Don't forget to add the ***Setter*** and ***Getter*** method, since the *serialize* and *deserialize* procedure will use it to construct your object. The important thing here is that the serialization procedure only care to your ***Setter*** method. So, even if you don't specify a variable as a class member, as long as there is ***Setter*** method exist, those variable with ***Setter*** method return type will be created in your database. And also, you need to match the name of ***Setter*** and ***Getter*** method to your database field name.

**2. Set Value to Field**

To set value to field, you only need to do the following:

```
User userObject = new User();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid).setValue(userObject);
```